# Direct click from a link to number composing

Tags: html, wordpress

Hi everyone first question here, thank you in advance. I need to create a webpage that from a link into an sms directs you to a page, which the exclusive function is to redirect you directly to the compose screen instead of having the user click on a button or image as an extra passage.

Comment: Question is unclear

Comment: Solved: 




<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    window.location.href = "tel:899482555";

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="load()">
    <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
    </html>